# Mtls on nginx - 400 Bad Request The SSL certificate error

Tags: nginx

I want to configure mtls on nginx load balancer (community version).
I found how to do it. I wrote 'ssl_client_certificate /path/CA.cert' and 'ssl_verify_client on' in nginx config, but when i open Nginx LB webpage i get error: 
400 Bad Request The SSL certificate error .

What is the problem?
Nginx config:

```
upstream server.com {
server 1.1.1.1:443;
server 1.1.1.2:443;
}
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name server.com;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.cer;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ca.pem;
ssl_verify_client on;
location / {
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
           proxy_read_timeout 5m;
           proxy_send_timeout 5m;
           proxy_pass https://server.com;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @knagode problem was in the certificate

Comment: did you buy the certificate at the very end? I managed to get it working with certs which are not signed by verified authority, however I can not manage to set it up if I buy e.g. the cheapest SSL cert on GoDaddy.com.

Comment: No, my company produces certificates, i took another one